# Deezer Javascript SDK getLoginStatus() returns previous session's information after logout

Tags: javascript, deezer

In my Deezer InApp, I call the Deezer Javascript SDK `DZ.getLoginStatus` function during my app initialization to get the currently logged-in user information. I noticed that if the user logs out from Deezer, their access token is correctly invalidated, but when they log back in, my app still gets the previous session's (now invalid) authentication information (with the `fromCookie` property set to `true`) in the `getLoginStatus` callback. I even get the previous session's information if I log in as a different user.

This problem causes my app's Deezer API requests to fail due to the invalid access token. Is there anything I can/should do in my app to clear the authentication cookie when the user logs out?

Comment: This bug is now fixed. You can try again if you want to. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same behavior when trying in desktop Chrome.

Comment: There were still problems, but it should be fixed now if you want to check

Comment: Thanks, I can confirm that the cookie gets cleared now if I log out and in again.